# R make the connection time longer

Tags: r

when I connect to a database, api, service, etc. I always met this error:

```
error in open.connection(con rb ) timeout was reached in r
```

sometimes there is some problem with the network, code, etc.

but sometimes I just need to wait longer time

in the second case, is there a way to make the connection time limit/threshold longer? so that I could finish the connection?

Comment: Is this using a specific package?

Comment: Unless your internet is super super slow it shouldn't timeout, I guess its more likely the authentication isn't configured correctly. Are you following the guide on the website? code.markedmondson.me/googleLanguageR/index.html

I guess `options(timeout = 4000000)` may help.

Comment: My internet is not stable, it disconnect once in a while, so I think make the program wait longer could be very helpful, let's see if there is a way to make it wait longer